# is there any way in c# to find the virtual disk drive details?

Tags: c#, windows

Say for example `D:` is the virtual drive; I need to know the following details of a virtual drive.

```
 1. on which HDD it is present
 2. virtual drive no.
 3. want to write a file to confirm the details
```

regards

Comment: Yes, you can..<http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383370.aspx>

Comment: @linguini Remove _>_ from the link to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323672%28v=vs.10%29.aspx) etc in the [VHD API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323700%28v=vs.10%29.aspx). This [blog post](http://www.jmedved.com/2009/05/open-and-attach/) contains some C# code using VHD, so might be a place to start.

If you can't get out all the information you need from that, maybe you at least get out enough information so that you then can use WMI to query for the rest, possibly using [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar.